# SVN Patching Word Document Files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are attempting to come up with a Centralized Document Repository. I am investigating the merits of using SVN to do this. I have read several treatises both here and on other sites that SVN is a good choice for this. But then I have a management scenario that I need help with. There is supposed to be a document review process for document changes. Currently this is not being followed like it should and one of the requirements for this project is to enforce this rule that document changes need to be approved.

My thoughts on how to do this is to only allow read access to those people with rights to edit the documents but then have read-write for those who are on the document approval board. However, I have been trying to use tortoise SVN as my client,and while I can diff a file with word and see the changes and such, I am not able to actually create a working patch of the file in order to submit it for review. If I can do this how do I do it? And if it can't be done this way, how would you suggest moving forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this is not possible at all, cause word files are a kind of binary and for this you can't created patches. You can diff two word files and see the differences but svn can't do that. May be you handle that with word itself...